# Trying to make a new workbook if there is data on a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to make a new workbook if there is data on a worksheet. works for 1 sheet but then get the error "subscript out of range" when it goes to the next

llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll

Edit 3:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks("orders (3)").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:AY300")) = 0 And Workbooks("orders (3)").Worksheets("Sheet2").Shapes.Count = 0 Then
    Workbooks("orders (3)").Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete

    Else
    Dim sWorkbook As Workbook

    'Create New Workbook
    Set sWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

    'Save Above Created New Workbook
    sWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CODE\11 Production.xlsx"
    End If


If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks("orders (3)").Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:AY300")) = 0 And Workbooks("orders (3)").Worksheets("Sheet3").Shapes.Count = 0 Then
    Workbooks("orders (3)").Worksheets("Sheet3").Delete

    Else
    Dim sWorkbook1 As Workbook

    'Create New Workbook
    Set sWorkbook1 = Workbooks.Add

    'Save Above Created New Workbook
    sWorkbook1.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CODE\22 Production.xlsx"
    End If

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks("orders (3)").Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:AY300")) = 0 And Workbooks("orders (3)").Worksheets("Sheet4").Shapes.Count = 0 Then
    Workbooks("orders (3)").Worksheets("Sheet4").Delete

    Else
    Dim sWorkbook2 As Workbook

    'Create New Workbook
    Set sWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Add

    'Save Above Created New Workbook
    sWorkbook2.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CODE\33 Production.xlsx"
    End If

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks("orders (3)").Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A1:AY300")) = 0 And Workbooks("orders (3)").Worksheets("Sheet5").Shapes.Count = 0 Then
    Workbooks("orders (3)").Worksheets("Sheet5").Delete

    Else
    Dim sWorkbook3 As Workbook

    'Create New Workbook
    Set sWorkbook3 = Workbooks.Add

    'Save Above Created New Workbook
    sWorkbook3.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CODE\44 Production.xlsx"
    End If

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks("orders (3)").Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A1:AY300")) = 0 And Workbooks("orders (3)").Worksheets("Sheet6").Shapes.Count = 0 Then
    Workbooks("orders (3)").Worksheets("Sheet6").Delete

    Else
    Dim sWorkbook4 As Workbook

    'Create New Workbook
    Set sWorkbook4 = Workbooks.Add

    'Save Above Created New Workbook
    sWorkbook4.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CODE\55 Production.xlsx"
    End If
```

Comment: If you don't specify which `Workbook` the `Worksheet` is in, then there's an implicit `ActiveWorkbook`. The active workbook may be the one you just added, not your original workbook, which is presumably `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: @BigBen I just updated above with my new code but i am still getting the same error

Comment: You still have instances of `Worksheets` that don't have the `Workbook` specified.

Comment: The error i am getting now is "Application defined or object defined error"

Comment: @BigBen just updated above with the new code but am still getting the same error

Comment: What line throws the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify the `Workbook` a `Worksheet` is in, then there's an implicit `ActiveWorkbook`. Looks like the active workbook is the one you just added, not your original workbook.

That said, this code can be simplified to something like this:

```
Sub teststs()
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then 'presumably you're skipping Sheet1, change as needed
             If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A1:AY300")) = 0 And ws.Shapes.Count = 0 Then
                  ws.Delete
             Else
                  Dim newWb as Workbook
                  Set newWb = Workbooks.Add

                  Dim i As Long
                  i = i + 11
                  newWb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CODE\" & i & " Production.xlsx"              
             End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How do i get it to skip 2 sheets?

Comment: I did : If ws.Name <> "orders (3)" & "Sheet 1" Then But it doesnt work

Comment: `If ws.Name <> "orders (3)" And ws.Name <> "Sheet 1" Then`